# Conditional formatting (alternating between only two colours) of rows depending on cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

How do i get conditional formatting done depending on values of cells.

I need to get the cells (and their rows) formatted in only two colours 
Say,A1 has Colour1
    if A2=A1, then A2 should get formatted to Colour1. 
    if A2 is not equal to A1 then A2 should get formatted to Colour2.
Similarly  if A3=A2,the A3 should get formatted to Colour of A2 or else the other colour.

Comment: What have you tried? have you taken a look at the conditional formatting options of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the solution you are looking for should involve macro (VBA) or not.
Anyway, as a first pass I'd suggest the following steps to achieve what you want.
Look at the following figure
[image]
Then use conditional formatting to change the color of the cells as you want.
Note: If you do not like to see the words "YES" "NO" then you can select the cells and change text color to GREEN and PINK respectively.
If you would want a VBA solution I'd be happy to give you.