# Excel 2019 Using VBA to colour sets of rows of cells w. two specific alternating colours, using unique value to identify which rows make a set

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, vba

Colour rows of cells w. two alternating colours?
Windows 10
Excel 2019

I have a spreadsheet that contains **31009 rows of data across 10 columns.**

The rows make up unique sets of data that belong together however, due to the shear number of rows
it would be easier to read if each unique set was a different colour from the set above and below it.

I have settled on two pastle colours that I would like to use but for ease of this question I wil use yellow and blue as examples.

Each set of data (many rows) has a unique reference number to identify it from the others.

It gets complicated in that the first Column (A) contains product types and the whole spread sheet is sorted alphabetically for ease of viewing.

New data (records) are not inserted at the end of the spread sheet (in the first empty cell), it is inserted at the appropiate alphabetical position, so...

Apple > Fresh
Apple > Juice
Apple > Sauce
Orange > Fresh
Orange > Concentrate << this is where the new entry for this product would be inserted by inserting the needed number of rows.
Orange > Juice
Potatos > Fresh
Potatos > Roasted

Is there a way, via VBA to tell excel to look down the column that contains the unique reference number and colour all of the rows for the first unique reference yellow, then the rows of the next unique blue, then the rows for the next unique number yellow, and the next unique rows blue, and on on and so forth all of the way down the 31009 rows?

I would also need the cell colours to update and shift down to the next unique number when a new one is entered in the middle of the sheet.

A user in the excelforum.com suggested the below, which works but it only colours 1 column and
requires a helper column which I can forsee could be a bit messy so that is why I am thinking that VBA is best for me.

Using helper column

in B2

```
=IF(A1=A2,B1,B1+1)
```

copy down

with CF

```
=ISODD(B2) yelllow

=ISEVEN(B2) blue
```

I have no idea if this is possible as I have spent hours and days searching online but I am no clearer as to the method hence why I am asking the experts here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: For the record, this is an example of a HELPFUL reply https://superuser.com/questions/893805/conditional-formatting-alternating-between-only-two-colours-of-rows-depending (not my question).

Comment: @Kenny you are pointing to a post that is 7 years old.  Things have changed.  This is not a site where one can post their wants and get code written for free.  That being said things like formula which are simple, sometimes that bar is lower, but you are asking for someone to spend their own precious time to write something for free.  This is more a site to help overcome a specific problem with existing code. Not write code based on a list of wants.  I too would have voted to close this based on the current rules and understanding of conduct.